# Views e variáveis de sessão disponível em sub domínios

Tags: php, laravel

Estou a criar um sistema web em laravel onde serão criados vários sub-domínios para localizar alguns serviços para os usuários. Ex. painel.dominio.com , loja.dominio.com, etc.

**Minha dúvida são:**

- Minhas variáveis criadas na sessão do domínio principal estarão
  acessíveis a todos os sub domínios ?
- Existe a possibilidade de gerenciar toda a aplicação no domínio
  principal fornecendo as views através de rotas para os sub domínios ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível compartilhar a sessão nativa do PHP pois são domínios diferentes. Neste caso você terá que utilizar um controle de sessão via Banco de Dados ou outra fonte de dados que seja acessível de modo comum entre todos domínios (principal + subdomínios) e levar a autenticação de um domínio para outro através de variáveis atreladas a requisição HTTP, seja via GET, POST ou HEADER.

Um sistema de Token também irá te ajudar nisto. Onde cada sessão criada por um usuário você gera um token, que ficará armazenado nesta fonte de dado comum, e quando você levar o usuário para outro domínio, você anexa esse token a requisição, conforme informado acima, e faz a validação do token na requisição recebida no novo domínio.